# AltBeacon getDistance() showing values as infinity

Tags: android, altbeacon

I am using AltBeacon library to detect nearby beacons. The app works and is able to detect my beacons. However, it is not able to calculate distance - I am getting distance measurement value as "Infinity".

This is my code :

```
beaconManager.setForegroundScanPeriod(5100l);
beaconManager.setForegroundBetweenScanPeriod(11000l);

if (beacons.size() > 0) {

    Log.i("Ranging", "inside detected : " + beacons.iterator().next().getDistance());
    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {

          Log.i("RangingActivity", "Got rssi as : " + beacon.getRssi() + " and distance " + beacon.getDistance());

     }
}
```

I get the following output in the log:

> Got rssi as -53 and distance Infinity

What is going wrong in the distance measurement?